# How to Run Python Script and pass its result to another component in a MERN app

Tags: python, python-3.x, reactjs, flask, mern

I have a MERN app and a Python Script .
For eg

Let the MERN app has 3 components : Home , Add , Display which gets rendered in App.js

```
function App(){
    return(
        <React.Fragment>
        <Router>
        <Route path="/" component={Home}/>
        <Route path="/Add" component={Add}/>
        <Route path="/Display" component={Display}/>
        </Router>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

Let's suppose I have a button in the  component . When I press the button I need to run a Python script and pass its result to  component and it has run its function in componentDidMount and eventually the  component displays the result .

I had used Python and React js seperatly . But not familiar with passing values and using them . Can anyone help on how to acheive this . My project is way complicated than this . I am using this just as an example to show my requirements .

Any small suggestion would be of much use .
Few sites suggest using Flask with it . I have no idea how to combine Flask with MERn . Is that the only way to achieve this

Thanks

Comment: Usually web applications get their dependencies from APIs. I would deploy whatever the python script does as a web service and consume in the web app... How are you deploying the whole set?

Comment: I haven't deployed it yet. Most probably will do it through Google Cloud Platform

Comment: Will you be able to install python in the environment in which you run the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/python-shell which can be a solution to your problem statement, the other hard way is to re write the entire program to node.js

Comment: I'm the other hard way type of guy

Answer (score 0):

You can use child_process available in Node JS to achieve this. Have a python script separately in your project and call it through Node using the child_process module. Go through this link to get more details about this:

https://dilmikottachchi.medium.com/integrating-python-with-the-mern-stack-59c060957710

Then you can call the API from your React JS front-end.